# Nested content controls in Word

Tags: ms-word

I'm looking at Word as part of a document generation solution for a law firm.  There are different documents that need to show/hide certain clauses/sections based on business rules and logic that can be fairly in depth - things like a specific judge in a specific county requiring certain information, so entire sections of the document may be shown or hidden based on this logic.

I'm aware of the Content Controls in Word, but is it possible to have nested content controls inside each other?  For example, let's say I have a dynamic paragraph (i.e. it might be shown or hidden based on some business rule) and that paragraph also needs to display the name of the plaintiff, which is retrieved from a database.

Our current solution uses a pseudo templating language inside of the Word docs that gets parsed out and replaced (something like `{FIELD "FIELD_NAME"}` which would insert the value of `FIELD_NAME`) and it seems to work fairly well but I'm curious if it couldn't be improved using built-in features of Word instead of custom software.

Is something like this possible?  I've found an article for Word that seems to indicate this exact scenario, but no articles or resources explaining how to actually achieve it.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you can nest other content controls within a rich text content control.

You can do this programmatically (in Word using VBA, or in a VSTO Add-In).

But first just try it in Word (enable the Developer ribbon, then insert a rich text control, then insert other content controls in that).  A rich text content control can contain paragraphs, tables etc (provided that it is block level, not run level).